# How can I store an image picked from the device in firestore 9.x.x using expo in a react native app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

What happens is that I am able to successfully store the information, and it creates a date, with the image path in the image field correctly, however the image doesnt get stored in the bucket.

Also I get an error saying "Error: Date could not be created" however it is created according to the database. Without the image picking function, the date gets stored, and created successfully without the error message. Here is the code  :

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const CreateScreen = () => { 
 const handleImagePick = async (uri) => {
    setImage(uri);
  }

  const openImagePicker = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [3, 4],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (!result.canceled) {
        const imageUri = result.assets[0].uri;
        handleImagePick(imageUri);
    }
  }

  const handleCreate = async (email) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (!currentUser) {
      alert("Error: Not logged in");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const dateRef = firebase.firestore().collection("dates").doc();
      await dateRef.set({
        title,
        location,
        image,
        date,
        requests: [],
        hosted_by: currentUser.uid,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
      // Upload image to Firebase Storage

      const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${dateRef.id}`);
      const response = await fetch(image);
      const blob = await response.blob();

      await uploadBytes(ref, blob);

      // Get URL of the image
      const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      setTitle("");
      setLocation("");
      setImage(url);
      setDate(new Date());
      alert("Date has been created successfully!");
      navigation.navigate("Home");
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Error creating date: ", error);
    }
  };

     <View style={{flex: 1, width: "100%", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={openImagePicker}>
          <Text>Select Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

and in my firebase config

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
-----------
-----------
-----------
-----------
};

// Initialize Firebase

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

export { firebase };
```

If anyone could help that would be fantastic, im really stuck

Comment: if you try to see the image from the firebase console, do you see it correctly or not? Moreover, add metadata on uploadBytes function, so it knows what kind of data you are sending:


const metadata = { contentType: "image/jpeg" };
const result = await uploadBytes(reference, blobFile, metadata)

Comment: @MauroRusso thank you for your response. It looks like that int he Firebase Database, i get the file path stored in images: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540mullerrobi%252Ffbauth/ImagePicker/caca5fb6-8d10-4b4c-9170-9fbbdb8c4f63.jpeg"

but when I check the firestore, there are no files. I extended the code with the metadata, but nothing happens.

Comment: also when I console log the image this is what I get

```

{"assets": [{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "height": 842, "rotation": null, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540mullerrobi%252Ffbauth/ImagePicker/1f1fe2c7-21ad-4c22-9421-2c250768f565.png", "width": 632}], "canceled": false, "cancelled": false}

```

Comment: are you sure that you are sending just the URI of the image? you don't have to send the whole image object, but just its uri. await fetch(imageUri) and then its blob